# ADB sideload regularly loads LineageOS ROM, but gets stuck at 0% with stock firmware, why?

Tags: adb, factory-reset, stock-rom, side-loading, factory-image

I'm trying to restore the stock firmware for a Samsung S10e.

It's currently setup with the LineageOS recovery image, and the LineageOS firmware.

I've rebooted in the (LineageOS) recovery, factory reset everything, and now I'm trying to sideloading the factory image (`G970foo_bar_baz.zip`), however, it's stuck at 0%.

If I try to sideload LineageOS again, it sideloads without any problem.

Should I keep waiting?

Since the factory ROM is very large (5.9GiB vs 800 MiB), it's possible that it's normal that it takes a long time before the sideload starts, however, I don't know how long should I wait.

Comment: Where did you got the factory image from? Are you sure it is designed to be side-loaded and not just a ZIP file for downloading multiple files together?

Comment: stock ROM flashable zips usually perform some health checks which you obviously cannot pass on modified device

Comment: @Robert ah. This could be the cause - the zip comes from sammobile.com, and it's described as "firmware" (https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-s10e/firmware/#SM-G970F), but I'm not entirely sure that it's the expected one.

Comment: @Robert Odin loaded the zip correctly (but I had to unpack it first), so you're correct that the firmware archive, as is, it's not intended to be sideloaded (I wasn't aware of the difference!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every ZIP file can be side-loaded.

I am not sure what properties need to be fulfilled by an ZIP file that can be side-loaded.

One indicator is the existence of the directory `META-INF/com/google/android/` inside the ZIP file. And inside there should be an file named `updater-script` which is required for installing the ZIP file via side-loading.

If that file is not present then most likely your ZIP file is not side-lodeable.